# Compute probabilities of balls not being drawn from urns

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

Independent events $A_1$ through $A_n$, where $A_n$ is event that nth ball is not drawn in a random draw from urn full of $n^2$ balls labeled $1, 2, \dots, n^2$

What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(A_n)$?

What is the $P(\bigcap_{n=2}^{\infty} A_n)$?

Comment: $n$ balls labeled $1,2,\ldots,n^2$ ??

Comment: @Math1000 not n balls. n square balls. I guess OP meant not n balls which are square but rather $n^2$ balls

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What does continuity have to do with this?

Anyway

1. $P(A_n) = \frac{n^2-1}{n^2}$.

Thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(A_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2-1}{n^2}$

2. $P(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n) = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_n)$ by independence

$\to \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_n) = P(A_1)P(A_2)P(A_3) \dots = 0P(A_2)P(A_3) \dots = 0$

$P(\bigcap_{n=2}^{\infty} A_n) = \prod_{n=2}^{\infty} P(A_n) = \prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n^2-1}{n^2}$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: 1. Why P(An) = (n-1) / n, rather than P(An) = (n-1) / (n^2)?

Comment: 2. Does the question 1 and 2 consistent with the continuity of the probability measure?

Comment: @J.ba Edited. What do you mean? I don't see how your question is related to continuity of probability measure.